# MassTransit: Generic SendFilter/PublishFilter is called multiple times when the message class inherits another class and/or implements interfaces

Tags: c#, .net-core, microservices, azureservicebus, masstransit

First of all, excuse my English, it's very bad. I am using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus for asynchronous communication between microservices. I need to use middleware filters to add metadata to message. The problem is that the filters for Send() and Publish() are instantiated once for each of the classes the message inherits from, and for each of the interfaces that it implements.
To register the filters I use the extension methods "UseSendFilter()/UsePublishFilter()".

**Is there a way that the send/publish filter is only invoked for the concrete type of the message?**

I leave an example that I hope can help you in understanding the problem.

**The Send Filter**

```
public class SendFilterTest<T> : IFilter<SendContext<T>> where T : class
{
    private readonly ILogger<SendFilterTest<T>> _logger;

    public SendFilterTest(ILogger<SendFilterTest<T>> logger = null)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? NullLogger<SendFilterTest<T>>.Instance;
    }
    public async Task Send(SendContext<T> context, IPipe<SendContext<T>> next)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"SendFilterInstance: {this.GetHashCode()}. MessageId: {context.MessageId}. NextType: {next.GetType().GetFriendlyName(shortName:true)} "); 
        }
        finally
        {
            // here the next filter in the pipe is called
            await next.Send(context);
        }
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateScope(this.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

**The filter registration generic method**

```
        //in this case sendFilterTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(SendFilterTest<>) }

     ...
        //send filters middleware register
        if (sendFilterTypes != null)
        {
            foreach (var sendFilterType in sendFilterTypes.Where(t => t != null))
            {
                cfg.UseSendFilter(sendFilterType, context);
            }
        }

        //publish filters middleware register
        if (publishFilterTypes != null)
        {
            foreach (var publishFilterType in publishFilterTypes.Where(t => t != null))
            {
                cfg.UsePublishFilter(publishFilterType, context);
            }
        }

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(shortMyQueueName, e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumers(context);
        });
    ...
```

**The Message Sent and its Interfaces**

```
public sealed class TestIntegrationCommand : IOutcomingCommand
{
    public Uri GetDestinationQueueUri()
    {
        return new($"queue:test-queue");
    }
}

[ExcludeFromTopology]
public interface IOutcomingCommand : ICommand
{
    [Obsolete("Use property 'Id' instead")]
    Guid CommandId => Id;
    Uri GetDestinationQueueUri();
}

[ExcludeFromTopology]
public interface ICommand
{
    Guid Id => Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

**The Send method**

```
...
   var testCommand = new TestIntegrationCommand();
   await (await bus.GetSendEndpoint(testCommand.GetDestinationQueueUri())).Send(testCommand);
...
```

**The Output**

```
[2021-04-07 20:15:49Z] info: UnitTests.DependencyInjection.CqrsServicesTest[0]
  StartTest
[2021-04-07 20:15:49Z] info: MassTransit[0]
      Configured endpoint test-queue, Consumer: UnitTests.TestDomain.TestAggregateConsumer

[2021-04-07 20:15:49Z] info: MassTransit[0]
      Configured endpoint test-queue, Consumer: UnitTests.TestDomain.TestEvent1Consumer
[2021-04-07 20:15:50Z] info: MassTransit[0]
      Bus started: sb://tms-testing.servicebus.windows.net/
[2021-04-07 20:15:50Z] info: UnitTests.Filters.SendFilterTest[0]
      SendFilterInstance: 17664976. MessageId: fc9e0000-01e6-64c9-bf0f-08d8fa01f04d. NextType: MergePipe<SendContext<UnitTests.TestDomain.TestIntegrationCommand>, SendContext<Tms.Framework.Cqrs.Core.Commands.ICommand>> 
[2021-04-07 20:15:50Z] info: UnitTests.Filters.SendFilterTest[0]
      SendFilterInstance: 39332178. MessageId: fc9e0000-01e6-64c9-bf0f-08d8fa01f04d. NextType: MergePipe<SendContext<Tms.Framework.Cqrs.Core.Commands.Outcoming.IOutcomingCommand>, SendContext<Tms.Framework.Cqrs.Core.Commands.ICommand>> 
[2021-04-07 20:15:50Z] info: UnitTests.Filters.SendFilterTest[0]
      SendFilterInstance: 26669753. MessageId: fc9e0000-01e6-64c9-bf0f-08d8fa01f04d. NextType: MergePipe<SendContext<UnitTests.TestDomain.TestIntegrationCommand>, SendContext<Tms.Framework.Cqrs.Core.Commands.Outcoming.IOutcomingCommand>> 
[2021-04-07 20:15:50Z] info: UnitTests.Filters.SendFilterTest[0]
      SendFilterInstance: 15215027. MessageId: fc9e0000-01e6-64c9-bf0f-08d8fa01f04d. NextType: Last<SendContext<UnitTests.TestDomain.TestIntegrationCommand>> 
[2021-04-07 20:15:51Z] info: UnitTests.TestDomain.TestAggregateConsumer[0]
      Consuming 'TestIntegrationCommand'. Id:UnitTests.TestDomain.TestIntegrationCommand. Count: 0. DO NOTHING!
[2021-04-07 20:15:51Z] info: MassTransit[0]
      Bus stopped: sb://tms-testing.servicebus.windows.net/
[2021-04-07 20:15:52Z] info: UnitTests.DependencyInjection.CqrsServicesTest[0]
      FinishTest
```

Thank you very much.

Regards

Borja

Comment: Thanks for finding this issue, I'm not sure how to address it yet but was able to reproduce it. It may help to [submit an issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues) to track it.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson, issue has submitted. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2429